# Periodic timer disposal not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a periodic timer of 5 seconds, where I am calling a function.

```
timer3 = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 5),
      (Timer t) => function());
```

The function is as below;

```
 Future<dynamic> function() async {
    var url = "https://rtdjiigwvh.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/preview_checkout";
    Map data = {};
    String body = json.encode(data);
        var res = await http
        .post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body)
        .then((value) {
      location = json.decode(value.body)["Location"].toString();
      print(location);
       if(location == 'ENTRY')
      setState(() {
              entry = true;
            });
      else if(location == 'EXIT')
      setState(() {
              exit = true;
              @override
              void dispose() {
              timer3?.cancel();
              super.dispose();
             }
            });
            if(exit == true)
            Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                NextScreen()));
    });
  }
```

Here when the boolean variable `exit` is true, I want the screen to redirect to the next screen, and also want to stop the polling which I am doing using the timer. Therefore I have used the `dispose` function for the timer to stop, but the problem is it won't stop right there and keeps on polling and refreshing the NextScreen continuously for every 5 seconds.
Kindly help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As noted by [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401399/), `dispose` should be a method on your `Widget`, not some local function (that is never called).  If that doesn't solve your problem, please show *where* you call `Timer.periodic`.  Usually the most common cause for leaked periodic `Timer`s is that more than one is created unwittingly.

Answer (score 0):

Dispose method should be defined outside of `function` method.
Move:

```
@override
void dispose() {
    timer3?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
}
```

outside and it will be automatically called when the statefulwidget gets disposed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds : 5)).then((){
  function();
});
```

instead of timer

Comment: This is not a *periodic* `Timer`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).